# How to change state of a component when the component is scrolled in view?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

Suppose I have a web structure as follows:

```
<Header />
<Component1 />
<Component2 />
<Component3 />
<Component4 />
```

Every component has a state as [component1Active, setComponent1Active] = useState(false)

Now, at the start Component1 is in view.

What I want is when component2 is scrolled in view, then I want to setComponent2Active = true and component1 as false.

I tried using useEffect, but it does not work as the states of all components are set as true during loading.

I am using functional components

Please help, any suggestions will be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: useEffect should be used for that, can you please show how did you use it?

Answer (score 1):

There is a react library on NPM called 'react-in-viewport'
https://github.com/roderickhsiao/react-in-viewport
Here is an example.

```
import handleViewport from 'react-in-viewport';

const Block = ({ inViewport, forwardedRef } ) => {
  const color = inViewport ? '#217ac0' : '#ff9800';
  const text = inViewport ? 'In viewport' : 'Not in viewport';
  return (
    <div className="viewport-block" ref={forwardedRef}>
      <h3>{ text }</h3>
      <div style={{ width: '400px', height: '300px', background: color }} />
    </div>
  );
};

const ViewportBlock = handleViewport(Block, /** options: {}, config: {} **/);

const App= () => (
  <div>
    <div style={{ height: '100vh' }}>
      <h2>Scroll down to make component in viewport</h2>
    </div>
    <ViewportBlock onEnterViewport={() => console.log('enter')} onLeaveViewport={() => console.log('leave')} />
  </div>
)
```

Using `const newComponent = handleViewport(<YourComponent/>)` you can create any component into one that has the `{inViewport, forwardedRef}` props, on the containing element of your component set the ref attribute equal to `forwardRef` then you can use the `inViewport` prop to determine if it is in view. You can also use the `onEnterViewport` and `onLeaveViewport` attributes of the component created by `handleViewport()` to know the visibility of the component.

You can add the library to your project through either of the cli commands

```
npm install --save react-in-viewport

yarn add react-in-viewport
```

You could also do this yourself by accessing the document DOM with a listener on the scroll event and checking scrollHeight of the page and comparing it to the scrollHeights of each component. Using the library makes the implementation much less of a headache.